# Read from an Excel spreadsheet, and rename multiple folders with data from XLSX

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that renames multiple folders in a specific directory, using data from an XLSX sheet, based on their name and timestamp (which are a part of the name as well, in `"COMXYZ_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"` format).

Folders in my directory will be in format of `"COM123_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"` or `"COM12_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"` or `"COM1_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"`.

The XLSX sheet will have the fields as:

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4 | FIELD5 | FIELD6 | FIELD7
COM12      A        B        C        D        E        F
COM23      A        B        C        D        E        F
```

I want the folders in my directory with the name `"COM12_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"` to be renamed as:

```
FIELD3_FIELD4_FIELD2_MMDDYYYY_FIELD5_NUMBER_FIELD6_FIELD7
```

where `NUMBER` (starting at 1) increases according to the timestamp in the name after the underscore `"_"`, and the date is according to the timestamp in the name as well for that specific COM#.

I have multiple folders with the same COM#, but with different timestamps. So far, I am able to rename 1 folder for each COM#, but the remaining folders are not being renamed.

Appreciate any and all help.

The code I've written so far with help from Aquiles' answer is:

```python
import os
import random
import string
import datetime
import re
import openpyxl
from collections import namedtuple
# Get Directories
directories = [name for name in os.listdir(r'.') if name.startswith('COM')]
# Load workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('database.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
rows = 20
for i in xrange(2, rows + 2):
    if ws['A%s' % i].value >= "":
        folder_to_change = [x for x in directories if x.startswith((ws['A%s' % i].value) + '_')]
        folder_to_change = folder_to_change[0] if len(folder_to_change) > 0 else None
        date_used = {}
        if folder_to_change:
            directories.remove(folder_to_change)
            # print folder_to_change
            folder_parts = folder_to_change.split('_')
            comport = folder_parts[0]
            timestamp = folder_parts[1]
            # print timestamp
            ts = re.search('(....)(....)(......)', timestamp)
            date = ts.group(2) + ts.group(1)
            # print date
            time = comport
            # print time
            date_used[comport] = 1 if comport not in date_used else date_used[comport] + 1
            # print date_used
            # print folder_to_change
            os.rename(
              folder_to_change,
              '{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}_{6}_{7}_{8}'.format(
                ws['B%s' % i].value,
                ws['C%s' % i].value,
                ws['G%s' % i].value,
                date,
                ws['D%s' % i].value,
                date_used[comport],
                ws['F%s' % i].value,
                ws['H%s' % i].value,
                ws['I%s' % i].value
                )
              )
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far?  Also, this is difficult if you are new to programming.  You might try breaking the problem into smaller tasks and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: @mareoraft 
So far I'm at scanning the directory for folders. Need to work on how to proceed from here onwards. I know it will be a difficult task, but I believe it would help me to get ideas and knowledge from people here.
`import os
import sys
import random

def get_immediate_subdirectories(folders):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(folders)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folders, name))]
print get_immediate_subdirectories(".")`

Comment: hey, so right now the problem is that it's not changing all the folders? That's because after the if ws['A%s' % i].value >= "" There should be a while or something so that all the folders that are in the folder_to_change list are changed. Good luck!

Comment: Changed the code in my answer a bit so you get the idea of what I'm talking about

Comment: @Aquiles Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it much. I will implement the changes today and update with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this and some of the indexes and stuff may not be the right ones, but you'll get the idea from this. I believe this could work:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import string

# Get directories
directories = [name for name in os.listdir('.')]

# Load Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xls')

# Load first work sheet
ws = wb[0]
rows = 10
dates_used = {}
for i in xrange(2, rows + 2):
    folder_to_change = [x for x in directories if x.startswith(ws['A%s' % i])]
    for y, folder in enumerate(folder_to_change):
        date = folder[8:16]
        os.rename(folder, '{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}_{6}_{7}'.format(
            ws['C%s' % i], ws['D%s' % i], ws['B%s' % i], date, ws['E%s' % i], 
            y+1, ws['F%s' % i], ws['G%s' % i])
```

Comment: Awesome, you gave me direction on how to approach it, appreciate it much. I am having difficulty trying to split the folder name at the "_" and use the date from the right hand side of the folder name instead of using defined numeric position 8-16.

Comment: to do that, if the name is split by a "_" you can use: file_name = folder.split("_") that will give you an array of all the names separated by "_", then you can use file_name[-1] to get the rightmost one. Then well, if you want to use the full string you leave it like that or if you want to take some portion you use the [:] format

Comment: Works as intended. Thanks a lot :)